# Is there explanation for usage of source in function(self, source) for HAS-A relation classes in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, composition

Can someone explain or reference documentation for explaining source as an argument in functions that is used in HAS-A relationship?

I am trying to improve my knowledge of OOP in python thus learning from: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html#inheritance-logic-gates-and-circuits. There is an example of Class inheritance and composition usage (1.13.2. Inheritance: Logic Gates and Circuits). I cannot understand the background of 'source' as a function argument of following code. I can see in debugging mode that whole instance of class is sent as argument. Is a 'source' reserved word? 
In code bellow - `class Connector HAS-A class LogicGate` and referencing function `tgate.setNextPin(self)` but in `BinaryGate` class there is `def setNextPin(self,source)` and my problem is around source reference.

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.name = n
        self.output = None

    def getLabel(self):
        return self.name

    def getOutput(self):
        self.output = self.performGateLogic()
        return self.output


class BinaryGate(LogicGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        super(BinaryGate, self).__init__(n)
        self.pinA = None
        self.pinB = None

    def getPinA(self):
        if self.pinA == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin A input for gate "+self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinA.getFrom().getOutput()

    def getPinB(self):
        if self.pinB == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin B input for gate "+self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pinB.getFrom().getOutput()

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pinA == None:
            self.pinA = source
        else:
            if self.pinB == None:
                self.pinB = source
            else:
                print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")

class AndGate(BinaryGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        BinaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):
        a = self.getPinA()
        b = self.getPinB()
        if a==1 and b==1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

class UnaryGate(LogicGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        LogicGate.__init__(self,n)
        self.pin = None

    def getPin(self):
        if self.pin == None:
            return int(input("Enter Pin input for gate "+self.getLabel()+"-->"))
        else:
            return self.pin.getFrom().getOutput()

    def setNextPin(self,source):
        if self.pin == None:
            self.pin = source
        else:
            print("Cannot Connect: NO EMPTY PINS on this gate")

class NotGate(UnaryGate):
    def __init__(self,n):
        UnaryGate.__init__(self,n)

    def performGateLogic(self):
        if self.getPin():
            return 0
        else:
            return 1

class Connector:
    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate
        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate

def main():
   g1 = AndGate("G1")
   g2 = NotGate("G2")
   c1 = Connector(g1,g2)
   print(g2.getOutput())

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple:

`setNextPin` in `Connector.__init__` is referencing to the `Connector` class as argument. And that is source that I was searching for.